How do I select a correct BGA underfill?
Several products we manufacture use fine (0.4mm) pitch BGA devices. In order to improve reliability, we are (by hand) applying BGA underfill to these devices. This is a type of adhesive which flows under the chip and helps to bond it strongly to the PCB.
Despite this, we are still seeing some boards fail during the production process (some time after the underfill has cured). We've seen boards fail during the following steps:

After underfill, then testing OK, then being bonded to a metal former with an epoxy at 130ºC.
Later in the production process having been temperature cycled to 105ºC.
After production is complete, and the board is undergoing burn in, where the temperature typically reaches 50ºC.

One theory is that the underfill compound has a different coefficient of thermal expansion to the solder balls, and so is stressing the solder when the board is heated later in the production process.
We are using Loctite 3513. These are flexi-rigid boards, and the BGAs are soldered on the rigid sections (which are 0.8mm FR4).
Questions:
Can the exact choice of underfill be the difference between improving reliability and reducing it?
If so, is there a best-practice way to select an underfill compound?

What is your definition of "fine pitch" BGA ?

@citizen - We're using a few different packages from 0.4mm to 0.5mm. We've seen failures on both of them.

"Fail during the production process".  Can you provide more details.  Were these failures during temperature or shock/vibration testing?  When were these failure first noticed - where in the production flow.

What is your board material?  Is it FR4, Polyimid, or something else?

Do you specify the IPC4101/xxx standard? They have different Tg values and time above Tg in reflow can be critical. Most of the materials go from around 35ppm / K to close to 300ppm / K (Z axis) above Tg.

@Rocketmagnet What process are you using, is this a controlled reflow process with components that are loaded by SMT and silkscreens that are machine controlled or hand loaded processes and a poor reflow oven. When do you add the underfill?


Was using underfill a response to a problem, or was it done from the start in anticipation of a problem? 2) Is the failure rate high enough to put aside some boards after the underfill stage and before anything else is done, then wait some time and see if any have failed even though there is no subsequent thermal stress?


At £90/20 ml you might be able to get expert advice directly from Henkel, for example if the 105 ºC stage could last for 25 mins (i.e., long enough to cure the underfill) perhaps that would be a better time to add it.

@SteveSh - Info added to the question.

@VoltageSpike - The boards are populated by a company with a good reputation, who we have visited and have confidence in their standard of work. Having said that, this batch of boards had a 25% failure rate on delivery. We sent back the failed boards for successful rework. Underfill is added by us at the very start of the production process, before anything else is done to the boards.

@AndrewMorton - Early on in the prototyping stage, I did kill a couple of boards by overstressing them. And I know that the boards may experience a little stress during production, and some small shock or vibration during use.

Thank you for all the comments everyone. All of these things you suggest are avenues I'm already investigating. Mostly though, I would like to understand more about BGA underfills, and how they relate to reliability. Does anyone have any examples of underfill reducing reliability?

Still need some more details,  The big ones being 1) what is the board material (FR4 is a no no in this kind of application) and 2) how big is the BGA package.  The bigger the package, the higher the stress on the balls or solder joints.

Also, did your design team do a stress analysis of the solder joints to see if underfill was really needed?

Have you done an X-ray of the BGA to find the failure? Do you know the failure mode? Until you know that it's a hunt in the dark.

These boards should not be failing due to solder joint cracking/fatigue during production temp  cycling which is like, what, 10 temp cycles.  Solder joint fatigue like this is something you might expect to see after tens of thousands of temp cycles, not a handful, even on an FR4 board, at least IMM.

We use <0.4 6 layer flex-rigid PCBA with several BGAs including a device with a 113-NFBGA footprint. During assembly the devices see several temperature cycles very similar to the one described. We had a time of very low yield because an epoxy "ripped" of the sealed bond wires - so the assumption of CTE missmatch is reasonable. However, the reliablity of the flex rigid is much more an issue in my experience. We had several cases of delamination. Can you confirm that it is the BGA joints and not e.g. failures in the PCBs itself?

@ChristianB. - I cannot say for sure exactly where the problem is. In the past, we've had some faulty boards x-rayed, but been unable to identify the fault visually. So I'm not sure how we could identify the cause of this fault.

@Rocketmagnet underfill can definitely reduce reliability if the wrong underfill is chosen for the job due to CTE mismatch. There is a lot of info about this online. One example that conglomerates the data: https://nepp.nasa.gov/files/23820/12_139_JPL_Ghaffarian_BOK%20Underfill%20Optimization%20for%20FPGA%20Package%20Assembly%20jpl%20pub%2012_13%20rec%209_29_12.pdf
I too have the question you have though, about how does one pick the right underfill with a primary reason of improving thermal stress lifetime vs shock/vibe? There is less of this online so I hope someone answers your question
